# How to separate Realm Object into two and get them into one variable?

Tags: realm

My goal to divide Realm.Object, so we can reuse specific object in different place. To reduce storage use.

The practical use would be:

1. call `realm.objects("ChatList")` to get the `lastMessage` value, without the need to get all of `Message` objects.

e.g reusing `User` Object. A `User` Object can be used in `Message` Object and `ChatList` Object.

`User` Object

```
const UserSchema: Realm.Object = {
  name: "User",
  properties: {
    user: "string",
    displayName: "string",
  }
}
```

`Message` Object

```
const MessageObject: Realm.Object = {
  name: "Message",
  properties: {
    user: "User",
    message: "string",
  }
}
```

`ChatList` Object

```
const ChatListSchema: Realm.Object = {
  name: "ChatList",
  properties: {
    name: "string",
    lastMessage: "Message",
  }
}
```

What I've did:

1. I have read about [Realm Data Model > Relationsihp](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/react-native/relationships/#std-label-react-native-to-many-relationship). It requires to explicitly define it in the `properties`

e.g.

```
const User: Realm.Object = {
  name: "User",
  properties: {
    name: "string", 
    tasks: "Task[]",
  }
};

const Tasks: realm.Object = {
  name: "Task",
  properties: {
    text: "string",
  }
}
```

However, I am not sure how to link `Task` to other object. e.g if I use it like this

```
const write = () => {
  realm.write(() => {
    realm.create("User", {
      name: "Jack",
      tasks: [
        {
          text: "Say 1",
        },
      ],
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: The question is vague. When you refer to saving storage space, do you mean disk space? Also - what does *reuse a specific object* mean? Objects are always re-usable and as long as they don't go out of scope, you can use them throughout an app. Lastly, in `1.`, you meantion getting the last object which in Swift is just `let lastObject = realm.objects("ChatList").last!` also noting that realm objects are lazily loaded so they take up almost no memory space and are only loaded when used. Can you clarify the question?

Comment: @Jay Thank you for the info. I will clarify my question, my question is "How to set properties of `ChatList` object with latest `Message` object in `Schema`". Currently, I do it manually, I create the `Message` object -> get the `ChatList` with primary key -> update the `ChatList` object. I wish to tell the `ChatList` schema to get the latest `Message` object with `properties` key e.g `{ identifier: channel-1 }`. So I can do `const chatList = realm.objects("ChatList")` and use it as props for `FlatList`. Is it possible?

Comment: Clarification of the question should be done in the question itself so other readers don't have to read through comments to understand the question. I am really not sure what you comments mean - you can't tell a schema to do something; a schema is a structure. Can you update the question further so we understand what you're asking an what you're trying to accomplish? Perhaps include some code you're having difficulty with? Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)